# configurar android studio con ionic, linux ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ionic3, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

tengo una consulta, instale android studio en linux ubuntu, sin embargo al trata de enlazar con ionic, colocando el comando:
ionic cordova build android
Me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hice todas las configuraciones de variables de entorno en:
  .bashrc
Y es el siguiente codigo:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
# avdmanager, sdkmanager
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
# adb, logcat
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
# emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
# ensure android is in PAth
export PATH="$HOME/Android/Sdk:$PATH"
```

Espero su ayuda, gracias, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Se solucionó el problema, era por permisos en las carpetas del *SDK* y tambien se reinició el equipo:

```
/Android/Sdk
```

Comment: Considero que para que esto sea wiki deberías ampliar por ejemplo que permisos y como supiste que eran esos

Comment: Piénsalo de este modo cuando alguien consulte tu pregunta y lea tu respuesta no sabrá cómo aplicar ti solución pues no dices ni cuáles permisos ni como aplicarlos